# Bootstrap 3 Tooltip does not work

Tags: javascript, css, symfony, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip

I have a problem with my bootstrap 3 tooltips.

I use the [Bootstrap Application Theme](https://themes.getbootstrap.com/product/application/).

Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6 margin_bottom_15">
    <a href="{{ path('list_course_teaching_events', {'course' : course.id }) }}"
        class="col-md-12 btn btn-block btn-primary-outline" 
        data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="ToolTipText">
        <i class="icon icon-arrow-bold-left"></i>
    </a>            
</div>
```

I also included [tether](http://%3Cscript%20src=%22//npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E) to get the tooltip js plugin work. 
I included also the js:

```
{# activate tooltips for this page #}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
</script>
```

And the tooltip plugin seems to work. But not in the right way:

[image: As u can see, the ToolTipText is on the left edge of the page]

As you can see, the ToolTipText appears on the left edge of the page no matter what align I write in the data-placement section and far away from my tooltip trigger which is in the middle of the page. And its plain text.

Do some of you have an idea of where the problem can be?

Here is a life version of the problem: [There is a button in the right](https://agotalk.com)

Comment: Check if styles for tooltips are included in your CSS

Comment: Yes it is! I can find it in the bootstrap.css

Comment: It would be nice if we can see it online

Comment: Ok. Here I putted a button with a tooltip on the main page - there is no user registration necessary. https://agotalk.com

Comment: There is a conflict. You use jquery-ui and Bootstrap together and both have tooltips and your code refer to jQueryUI and that's why you don't have any styles.

Comment: Thank u very much. That solved the problem. The solution is: I load jQuery UI before bootstrap. Thanks!